# row sum based on matrix with logicals

Tags: r, sum

I have two dataframes that look similar to this example:

```
> matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

```
> matrix(rexp(9), 3) < 1
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I want to sum individual entries of a row, but only when the logical matrix of the same size is TRUE, else this row element should not be in the sum. All rows have at least one case where one element of matrix 2 is TRUE.

The result should look like this

```
     [,1]
[1,]   12
[2,]    5
[3,]    9
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying your T/F matrix by your other one will zero out all the elements where `FALSE`. You can then sum by row.

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m2 <- matrix(rexp(9), 3) < 1

as.matrix(rowSums(m1 * m2), ncol = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We `replace` the elements to `NA` and use `rowSums` with `na.rm`

```
matrix(rowSums(replace(m1, m2, NA), na.rm = TRUE))
#     [,1]
#[1,]   12
#[2,]    5
#[3,]    9
```

---

Or use `ifelse`

```
matrix(rowSums(ifelse(m2, 0, m1)))
```

#### data

```
m1 <-  matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m2 <- matrix(rexp(9), 3) >= 1
```